# Openstreet Maps Tile render performance - 9 secs to render a new tile

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm having a performance issue rendering new tiles with **renderd** and openstreetmaps.

I have 3 very power servers on a SSD SAN, and some servers with local SSD storage. To get right to the point, non-cachced tiles are taking RenderD about 9 seconds to render at any zoom level I have not pre-rendered (I believe I’ve gone level 14 or so -- ).

I’m done
Modify postgres conf file with all the recommended buffer settings
150gigs + of RAM
32 processors
Added a lot of extra recommended indexes

Nothing affects the performance at all – It’s stuck at about 9 seconds to render each new tile with zero server load.

Curious where to start – I even had a Postgres expert look to see what if any indexes could help…We added quit a few, but alas, nothing really made a difference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Start by turning on track_io_timing, then looking at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the slow queries.  You can use [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to capture this automatically.

Comment: I have a pretty heavy mySQL background, but very limited in Postgres; will be a bit of a learning curve. Any suggestions on tutorials or docs on output from track_io_timing etc?

Comment: I'm not aware of good docs on  track_io_timing's output in plans, I think it is supposed to be self explanatory.

Comment: Found that some queries are taking 6-12 seconds. Used Explain ... Would like to post it here but i'm limited

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/mn8rp#html

Comment: The sort is bafflingly slow.  What is the locale/collation of your database?  Or if your table columns don't follow the default, what are their collations?

Comment: The gather is also slower than it seems like it should be.  If you turn off parallel query (`set max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 0;`), it should at least make the plan easier to understand.

Comment: I misread your comment - Database collation for GIS is en_US.UTF-8